# How to extract attribute value in XML using xpath in mule

Tags: xpath, attributes, mule

I want to extract the value of an attribute  from my xml.
But I am getting null as a result.
Please check if the following code snippet is correct or not.

## Mule Config File

```
<mulexml:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="false">
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="argo" uri="http://www.x.com/argo/" />
</mulexml:namespace-manager>
<flow name="kFlow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\im\Desktop" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" moveToDirectory="">
        <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="ACK.xml" caseSensitive="true"/>
    </file:inbound-endpoint>
    <file:file-to-string-transformer doc:name="File to String"/>
    <logger message="#[xpath('//argo:ackTransactions/argo:ackTransaction/@argo:ediAckTransactionType').text]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

</flow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the exact same namespace:

```
<mulexml:namespace prefix="argo" uri="http://www.navis.com/argo" />
```

Comment: Thanks David Dossot. I used the exact name space and its working now. By mistake one / at the end was added

Comment: @mule-user Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/232266 to learn how to properly accept an answer on StackOverflow.